# Changing date/time column into date 24hr time

Tags: r, datetime, strptime

Example data:
[Chunk of table with both types of date/time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sRLr.png)

```
SITE                         DATE.TIME              TEMP
Shacklefordck_w_2018         10/29/18 11:30:00AM    22.202
TompkinsCk_w_2014             5/14/2014 8:00        21.461
```

I have a date/time column in the format `m/d/yy H:M` however some times in the column are in 12hr with AM/PM and some times are 24hr. I want them all in 24 hour so that I can then use `strptime` to separate the date and time into two different columns. This problem came up because I keep getting NA using this code:

```r
Time <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(bigdf$DATE.TIME, "%m%d%Y %H:%M", tz="")), format = "%H:%M")
Date <- format(as.POSIXct(strptime(bigdf$DATE.TIME, "%m%d%Y %H:%M", tz="")), format = "%m%d%Y")

bigdf$DATE <- Date
bigdf$TIME <- Time
```

I want all of my date/time entries to be `m/d/yy H:M` in 24 hr without the AM/PM. 
I've tried

```r
newbigdf <- as.Date(bigdf$DATE.TIME, format= "%m%d%Y %H:%M") 
bigdf$DATE.TIME <- newbigdf #nope still NA
```

Comment: Is the column `DATE.TIME` a string?  One quick thought is that you can use `grep()` with the appropriate regular expression pattern to determine which times are formatted as 24hr and 12hr in your data.frame.  From there, simply apply the appropriate `strptime` function to each value convert it to the desired format.

Comment: if my answer correctly addressed you're question, do remember to accept it, or give feedback on why its not suitable :)

Answer (score 0):

Following my comment...

1. Use `grep` + regular expressions to identify different formats
2. Use `grep` results to apply appropriate conversion to `POSIXct`

```r
# Make example dataframe with different datetime formats
df <- data.frame(string = c("10/29/18 11:30:00AM",
                            "10/29/18 4:30:00PM",
                            "5/14/2014 8:00",
                            "5/14/2014 14:00"), 
                 stringsAsFactors = F)

# Use RegEx to ID different formats
idx.1 <- grep(df$string, pattern = "\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}\\s")
idx.2 <- grep(df$string, pattern = "\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2}\\s")

#  Add format column to df
df$format[idx.1] <- 1
df$format[idx.2] <- 2

## Apply POSIX conversions
df$POSIX[idx.1] <- as.POSIXct(df$string[idx.1], format = "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
df$POSIX[idx.2] <- as.POSIXct(df$string[idx.2], format = "%m/%d/%y %I:%M:%S%p")
df$POSIX <- as.POSIXct(df$POSIX, origin = "1970-01-01")

df
```

results in the data.frame:

```
               string format               POSIX
1 10/29/18 11:30:00AM      2 2018-10-29 11:30:00
2  10/29/18 4:30:00PM      2 2018-10-29 16:30:00
3      5/14/2014 8:00      1 2014-05-14 08:00:00
4     5/14/2014 14:00      1 2014-05-14 14:00:00
```

#### Regular Expression + grep

The easiest way to differentiate the formats is by noting the new dates use 2 digit years, while the earlier date format uses 4 digit years.  Following this, the regex search pattern:

```r
"\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2}\\s"
```

can be interpreted as:

`"(1-2 digits)/(1-2 digits)/(2 digits)(space)"`

will correctly identify the 2 digit year date formats.  Note the double backslashes when using regex patterns in R.